# How can i put the top of my component fixed

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

How can i put my component 'MyTitle' static, i mean the top of that component have to fixed, because if the 'MyForm' grow vertically, the MyTitle component ahead to top until disapear, how can i solve that? or the wrong is <Space ? i dont care if the solucion should be with css or antd

```
<Space direction="vertical" size={100}>
          <MyTitle  />
          <Card className="card">
             <MyForm />
          </Card>
        </Space>
```

these are the mocks

```
-----------------------------
         my title
-----------------------------


           card

-----------------------------
```

When the card use to grown, and the title disappear

```
                             ^
          my title           ^
-----------------------------


          card










-----------------------------
```

Comment: There is no way to answer this with the info you have provided. I'm unsure what this means "How can i put my component 'MyTitle' static"

Comment: @RossMoody i made a change in my question

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use position: fixed and give fixed width

Comment: its a comment? no an answer